# When would you use 相互 as opposed to お互い？

Tags: words, wago-and-kango

I'm thinking the former is slightly more hard/archaic, and for written style japanese, where was the latter is more conversational? But they both seem to have the same meaning.

Comment: Related: https://hinative.com/ja/questions/1113684. As a hint, お in お互い used as honorific between speakers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm thinking the former is slightly more hard/archaic, and for written style japanese, where was the latter is more conversational? But they both seem to have the same meaning.

- 相互 is slightly more hard: yes.
- 相互 is slightly more archaic: no.
- 相互 is for written style: yes
- お互い is more conversational: yes.
- they both seem to have the same meaning: yes.

Jisho.org defines them as:

> [相互{そうご}](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%B8%E4%BA%92)
>   Noun, No-adjective
>   1. mutual; reciprocal
>
> [お互{たが}い](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8A%E4%BA%92%E3%81%84)
>   Noun
>   1. mutual; reciprocal; each other
>   Polite form of 互{たが}い
>
> [互{たが}い](http://jisho.org/search/%E4%BA%92%E3%81%84)
>   Noun
>   1. mutual; reciprocal​

According to the above definitions, 相互 and お互い/互い seem to have the same meaning and be interchangeable except for 相互 having No-adjective as a part of speech and except for お互い being polite.

However, their actual use or nuance is slightly different, and they are not always interchangeable.

As for **お互いに**/**互いに** and **相互に** which are the adverbial forms of お互い/互い and 相互 respectively, they have the same meaning as "*mutually; with each other; reciprocally; together*", and are almost interchangeable.

But, as for **お互｛たが｝い様{さま}** which is often used in a conversation or in salutation meaning "*we are of equal status in this regard*", **お相互｛そうご｝様{さま}** or **相互｛そうご｝様｛さま｝** doesn't make sense at all.

I think the biggest difference between 相互 and お互い/互い is that the former can make compound words as follows, while the latter cannot.

- 相互作用{そうごさよう} *interaction*
- 相互理解{そうごりかい} *mutual understanding*
- 相互交流{そうごこうりゅう} *mutual exchange*
- 相互運用性{そうごうんようせい} *interoperability*
- 相互扶助{そうごふじょ} *mutual aid*
- 相互協力{そうごきょうりょく｝*bilateral cooperation*

The difference in the nature of both largely comes mainly from the word where they were born.
お互い/互い are *[Yamato kotoba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamato_kotoba)* (大和言葉) or *Wago* (和語), which are native Japanese words, while 相互 is *Kango* (漢語) or [Sino-Japanese vocabulary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Japanese_vocabulary), which refers to that portion of the Japanese vocabulary that originated in Chinese or has been created from elements borrowed from Chinese.

The major difference between *Wago* and *Kango* reflected in お互い/互い and 相互, in general, is that the former has a comprehensive meaning, is not official, is suitable for colloquial use and has emotional nuance, whereas the latter has a relatively strict meaning, is suitable for official usage and written language, and has a descriptive nuance.

A related article: [What are the differences between わけ and 理由?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53673/what-are-the-differences-between-%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91-and-%E7%90%86%E7%94%B1/53690#53690)

Comment: @Chocolate: いつもありがとう。英語もっと勉強しないといけません。