# What is the difference between 「変更」 and 「変化」?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I came across the word 「変化」 meaning "change, alteration". I already know the word 「変更」 that means "change" as well. What is the difference between both terms?

I found a related question where they discuss [変わる vs 変化](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54638/32952), but they say nothing on 変更。

よろしくお願いします！

Answer (score 13, accepted):

変更 specifically refers to a human-caused update/modification of a plan, project, document, destination, etc. 変化 refers to change in general.

As suru-verbs, 変更する is transitive, and 変化する is intransitive.

For example, you can say 季節の変化 but not 季節の変更. You can say 計画を変更する but not 計画を変化する.